# Parsing JSON dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I'm decoding a JSON response from an API. Normally I would just add the results to an array which I can then access in my views later, but with the API I am working with right now it does not return the results in an array. How can I store my JSON data so that I can use it within my views?

Here is my function that fetches my data:

```swift
func loadStats(name: String) {        
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://leetcode-stats-api.herokuapp.com/\(name)")
    else{return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, resp, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stats.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Nedd to store 'res' into something
            }
            
        }catch{
            print("Failed to Decode: \(error)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Here is my JSON response:

```json
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "retrieved",
    "totalSolved": 121,
    "totalQuestions": 2463,
    "easySolved": 73,
    "totalEasy": 604,
    "mediumSolved": 45,
    "totalMedium": 1314,
    "hardSolved": 3,
    "totalHard": 545,
    "acceptanceRate": 56.63,
    "ranking": 461292,
    "contributionPoints": 222,
    "reputation": 0,
    "submissionCalendar": {}
}
```

Here is my struct:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Stats: Codable, Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let status: String
    let message: String
    let totalSolved: Int
    let totalQuestions: Int
    let easySolved: Int
    let totalEasy: Int
    let mediumSolved: Int
    let totalMedium: Int
    let hardSolved: Int
    let totalHard: Int
    let acceptanceRate: Double
    let ranking: Int
    let contributionPoints: Int
    let reputation: Int
}
```

Comment: It would help if you specificed how you intend to use the data once saved as it could be stored in many different ways depending how it was to be used.  You have already 'parsed the json dictionary` so the title could be better-formed too

Comment: I am able to print the data within loadStats function but when I try to use that data in my view it is nil

Comment: As you say, you need to store the API results in "something". But as you still haven't provided any context we can't help with way that "something" is.  The problem you're almost certainly having is the the view is accessing the data before you've saved it into wherever the view is looking for it (i.e. the view is synchronous, the loader asynchronous).

Comment: I have saved the data using a published var called stats. so it looks like this: self.stats = res. I am calling the function using a button in a different view where I am able to enter in the username for the name parameter of the function. When I hard code the name into he loadStats function and call it in the init function I am able to display the data, But calling the function using a button is not saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the decoding is successful, you'll end up having a `Stats` object stored in `res`.

Now, the question is `How can I store my JSON data so that I can use it within my views?`.

The answer depends on whether you are using a view model, or not.

If you are using a view model, declare an `@Published` property and set your decoded `res` variable's value to it, like so:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stats: Stats?

    ...

    func loadStats(name: String){ 
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://leetcode-stats-api.herokuapp.com/\(name)")
        else{return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, resp, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stats.self, from: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.stats = res
                }
                
            }catch{
                print("Failed to Decode: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then you can use in your view, like so:

```
struct AView: View {
    @StateObject private let viewModel = ViewModel()

    ...

    var body: some View {
        if let stats = viewModel.stats {
            // here you can use it as soon as `loadStats` finishes
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not using a view model, declare an `@State` property to the view that has the `loadStats` function and set your decoded res variable's value to it, like so:

```
struct AView: View {
    @State private var stats: Stats?

    ...

    var body: some View {
        if let stats {
            // here you can use it as soon as `loadStats` finishes
        }
    }

    func loadStats(name: String){ 
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://leetcode-stats-api.herokuapp.com/\(name)")
        else{return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, resp, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stats.self, from: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.stats = res
                }
                
            }catch{
                print("Failed to Decode: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Several problems with this answer:  It assumes SwiftUI which the question doesn't indicate, the 'body' isn't returning 'some View', and it doesn't address the disjoint between the async nature of the API call and real-time display of the view.

Comment: First, the poster edited out the `swiftui` tag, hours after I posted the answer! (you can see it yourself) Second, I didn’t write code to display the data, because that’s not what the user asked; they asked how to store and access the data, which I did show!

Comment: I Never edited out the part of it not being swiftUI the user TylerP edited my original question. This project IS in swiftUI. Regardless I appreciate your answer however it did not work.

Comment: Which of the 2 cases did you try?